# Why do CFM templates being included with cfinclude need their own <cfoutput> wrappers?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I am using `<cfinclude>` to include various pages within a master page. In my master page all the body content is wrapped in `<cfoutput>` tags. However I noticed that after testing, the included .cfm page don't see the `<cfoutput>` tags at all and hence don't display the dynamic data.

```
<body>
  <cfoutput>
  <cfinclude template="page1.cfm" />
  <cfinclude template="page2.cfm" />
  <cfinclude template="page3.cfm" />
  </cfoutput>
</body>
```

In the above example, the included templates that have dynamic data in them will not display properly. To solve this I have to add `<cfoutput>` tags within each of the CFM files. How come they can't use the `<cfoutput>` tags that are already there within the body?

Comment: What kinds of things do you have in `pageX.cfm` .  I have never had to wrap `<cfincludes>` like this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because each CFML file is compiled separately, and whether or not to output something is determined at compile time, not runtime.

Comment: okay thanks, I thought I had configured something incorrectly!

Answer (score 1):

Set aside how ColdFusion works, you want to do this.  The point of using something like CFINCLUDE is that you're able to write a chunk of code once and use it in multiple situations.
Think of it as a poor mans' encapsulation.  Someone should be able to use that included template without getting bogged down in the mundane details of the template that is being included.